# Basic Authentication question

Tags: authentication

Recently i read about the basic authentication they are saying that

Basic authentication is doesn't rely on session tracking.

What does it means?

We no need to maintain the username and password in session?

Thanks in advance

Dilip

Comment: This link - http://www.dickbaldwin.com/java/Java695.htm - should help you clarify some concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic auth is done between browser and server, not browser and web application. The web application is not even aware of it (although some frameworks offer that as a feature by returning http responses). There is also no login and logoff call, just username password present or not.

- No Authentication string present, server returns 401 Authorization Required.
- Authentication string present, return requested page.